# Inserting/Checking data in Core Data increasing memory in activity monitor

Tags: objective-c, macos, core-data, automatic-ref-counting

Here is a code witch inserts and checks some data (100 records per minute). As result it increases memory in Activity Monitor.

Also the problem is that after several hours of working cache.sqlite is up to 5 Mb but in activity monitor I see that app takes more than 100 Mb and keeps growing

Using Xcode 7 instruments I don't see any memory leaks.

Please help me with resolving the issue:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSManagedObjectContext* moc;
...

- (BOOL)addCache:(NSData *)aHash
{
    BOOL isAdded = NO;

    @autoreleasepool {

        DOMCItem* messageCacheItem = (DOMCItem *)[DOMCItem insertInManagedObjectContext:_moc];
        messageCacheItem.contentkey = aHash;

        NSArray *objArr = [[_moc registeredObjects] allObjects];
        [_moc obtainPermanentIDsForObjects:objArr error:nil];

        if([_moc save:nil]) {

            isAdded = YES;
        }

        for (NSManagedObject *mo in [_moc registeredObjects]) {
            [_moc refreshObject:mo mergeChanges:NO];
        }

        [_moc reset];
    }

    return isAdded;
}

- (BOOL)isCached:(NSData *)aHash
{
    BOOL isCached = NO;

    @autoreleasepool {

        NSEntityDescription* ed = [DOMCItem entityInManagedObjectContext:_moc];
        NSFetchRequest* fr = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
        [fr setEntity:ed];
        NSPredicate* pr = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"key == %@", aHash];
        [fr setPredicate:pr];
        [fr setFetchLimit: 1];

        NSArray* arr = [_moc executeFetchRequest:fr error:nil];

        if ([arr count] > 0) {

            isCached = YES;
        }
    }

    return isCached;
}
```

Comment: Is the managed object context persistent?  Contexts cache objects, and it's totally normal for memory usage to go up as you insert new objects, especially as they are faulted.  Memory pressure will cause the context, first to fault the objects, and if pressure continues, to discard the cache altogether.

Comment: the problem is that cache.sqlite is up to 5 Mb but in activity monitor I see that app takes more than 100 Mb and keeps growing